# Select word in char array and compare it one by one

Tags: c++, c-strings

Supposed I have a char array, which contains duplicate words, I am going to delete it without using **string library** but **cstring library** only.

*****The Sample Text******

**One one one** of the most famous titles in the short story genre is a must-read. The story is about a young couple and how they meet the challenge of buying each other a Christmas gifts when they don't have enough **money money money**.

*****The Edited Text******

**One** of the most famous titles in the short story genre is a must-read. The story is about a young couple and how they meet the challenge of buying each other a Christmas gifts when they don't have enough **money**.

I have stored the text in to a char array and convert the text into capital letter.

```
char str[100];
```

But how can I get the word and compare them one by one? Some of them even contain punctuation. Like "money money." and it is duplicate as well.

Comment: Why have you flag `C++` if you only want to use C types and C functions ? And use [`strpbrk`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strpbrk/) to find word separators and [`strstr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/) to find identified word inside char

Answer (score 2):

I think you can't use separator functions because you want to keep spaces and punctuations. I have a solution for your problem and i think you can get an idea from the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

#define MAX_ITEM_LENGTH 20
#define MAX_ITEM_COUNT 200
#define MAX_STRING_LENGTH 1000

char delimeters[] = {' ', ',', '.', '-'};

bool equals(char* str1, char* str2, int length1, int length2){
    if(length1 != length2)
        return false;
    for(int i = 0; i < length1; i++)
        if(toupper(str1[i]) == toupper(str2[i]))
            return true;
    return false;
}

int parse(char* str, char*** result){
    int index = 0;
    int totalCount = 0;

    for(; totalCount < MAX_ITEM_COUNT && str[index] != '\0' ; totalCount++){
        for (int resultIndex = 0 ; resultIndex < MAX_ITEM_LENGTH; resultIndex++){
            if (resultIndex > 0 && strchr(delimeters,str[index])){
                break;
            }
            (*result)[totalCount][resultIndex] = str[index];
            index++;
            if(strchr(delimeters, str[index-1]))
                break;
        }
    }

    return totalCount;
}

int removeDuplicates(char** items, int itemsLength, char*** result){
    char* lastItem = new char[MAX_ITEM_LENGTH];
    int index = 0;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < itemsLength ; i++){
        if(equals(items[i], lastItem, strlen(items[i]), strlen(lastItem))){
            index--;
            continue;
        }

        strcpy((*result)[index++], items[i]);
        if(!strchr(delimeters, items[i][0])){
            strcpy(lastItem, items[i]);
        }
    }

    return index;
}

int main() {
    char str[MAX_STRING_LENGTH] = "One one one of the most famous titles in the short story genre is a must-read. The story is about a young couple and how they meet the challenge of buying each other a Christmas gifts when they don't have enough money money money.";
    char** items;
    char** result;
    items = new char*[MAX_ITEM_COUNT];
    result = new char*[MAX_ITEM_COUNT];
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_ITEM_COUNT; i++){
        items[i] = new char[MAX_ITEM_LENGTH];
        result[i] = new char[MAX_ITEM_LENGTH];
    }

    int itemsLength = parse(str, &items);
    int resultLength = removeDuplicates(items, itemsLength, &result);
    for(int i = 0; i < resultLength; i++)
        cout<<result[i];

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you cokceken, but I am not familiar with you code. In parse(), why 
"if(strchr(delimeters, str[index-1])) break;" need to apply?

Comment: strchr returns a non-zero number if str[index-1] (for example ',' character) exists in delimeters string(true in our case). If we have a string like "array," we need to stop at ',' and don't include it in the word. With this control we parse "array," as {"array", ","} not {"array,"}

Comment: Thank you again. However, I found some wired things. How come sometimes you use (*result)[totalCount][resultIndex] = str[index]; and sometimes you use strcpy((*result)[index++], items[i]); ?

Comment: At first we need to get characters one by one for parsing. And then we have all parts as different strings we just copy them as we need.